# Find out whether the number is a prime element of the ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need to find out whether the number $\ 4+\sqrt{-5}\ $ is a prime element of the ring $\ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

To be honest, I just don't have a clue how I can start the solution. So, if someone could just give me a hint, I would be very greatful.

Comment: Can you write out the definition of prime with $4+\sqrt{-5}$ substituted in?

Comment: If $4+\sqrt{-5}=pq$, then $21=4^2+5=(4+\sqrt{-5})(4-\sqrt{-5}))=p\overline{p}q\overline{q}$. Where $\overline{p}=x-y\sqrt{-5}$ for $p=x+y\sqrt{-5}$. Then $a=p\overline{p}$ and $q\overline{q}$  are rational integers positive divisors of $21$. You have the options $a=1$, which gives $p=\pm1$, or $a=\pm3$, but $x^2+5y^2=3$ has no solutions, or $a=7$ which gives $b=3$, which for the same reasons has no solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, you can define the norm of an element $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ as $$|a+b\sqrt{-5}|=a^2+5b^2.$$ One can show that this norm is multiplicative (i.e., $|xy|=|x|\cdot|y|$ whenever $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$). Also, the only units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ are $\pm 1$. More precisely, an element is a unit iff it has norm $1$. Note that $|4+\sqrt{-5}|=21$ so if $4+\sqrt{-5}$ were not a prime then there must exist $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ such that $4+\sqrt{-5}=xy$ and $|x|=3$ and $|y|=7$ which is clearly impossible.

Comment: So, let me just make it a little bit clearer. Suppose $4+\sqrt{-5}$ could be represented as $pq$. Then it would mean that $N(p)=3$ and $N(q)=7$ (or vice versa) where $N$ -- is a norm function. Since p and q are complex numbers, it means that the equations $a_1^2+b_1^2=3$ and $a_2^2+b_2^2=7$ (where $p=a_1+b_1i$ and $q=a_2+b_2i$) must have whole roots. But it is impossible, therefore $4+\sqrt{-5}$ is a prime element of the ring. Am I right?

Comment: That's exactly correct! We have $4+\sqrt{-5}=4+\sqrt{5}i$ and the square of the complex norm of that is $4^2+5=21$.

Comment: Thank you! Now it is clear to me.